# Registration Button not working on CiviCRM Event Page

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Ok So I am working on CiviCRM 5.19.2 and WordPress 5.6.  I've created an event in CiviEvent and set it to active.  My Event page has the following shortcode

[civicrm component="event" action="info" id="8" hijack="1"]

which leads to the event information page as it should.  However, the Register Here button isn't working.  It just resets to the event information page again.  If I add the shortcode for the registration page

[civicrm component="event" action="register" id="8" hijack="1"]

to the same Event Page, it leads to a list of events with more links that don't work.

I've temporarily bypassed the event info page so that my participants can register but I'd like that event info page in place with a working link.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM 5.19 is not compatible with WP 5.6.   WP 5.5 had a change that required an update which is in CiviCRM 5.26 https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice

I'd recommend CiviCRM 5.32.2 currently as that version has all the security fixes in 5.28 (latest security version) as well many other bug fixes/enhancements.

Please look at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/#civicrm-529  as this further documents some of the follow up changes that affect Paths and URLs in WP